# Use IMemoryCache with Unity DI Container in ASP.net core application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, caching, dependency-injection, unity-container

I want to use `IMemoryCache` in my ASP.Net Core application but the issue is that I don't know how to register this in Unity DI container which is used instead of default DI implementation.

If I would use default DI it works out the box by adding

```
services.AddMemoryCache();
```

Line to the *startup.cs*.

So I would appreciate any ideas which will help me to use `IMemoryCache` with Unity DI as for now I'm getting the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: The current type,
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.IMemoryCache, is an interface and
>   cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

DI part from startup:

```
public void Configure (IApplicationBuilder app, IStringLocalizer<Startup> stringLocalizer)
        {
           InitializeContext ();

....

private static void InitializeContext ()
{
    var container = new UnityContainer ();

    UnityConfigurationSection section
        = (UnityConfigurationSection) ConfigurationManager.GetSection ("unity");
    section.Configure (container, "primaryUnityContainer");

    var resolver = new UnityDependencyResolver (container);

    container.RegisterInstance<IDependencyResolver> (resolver);

    DependencyContext.Initialize (resolver);

}
```

UPDATE:

It's a legacy Unity DI Container from Microsoft.Practices.Unity namespace which cannot be used as default DI for .net core

Comment: Are you using any integration for the container? Check https://github.com/unitycontainer/microsoft-dependency-injection

Comment: `IDependencyResolver` is not part of asp.net-core. what version is your project?

Comment: @Nkosi Unity DI implementation has to be like this as it's needed for legacy components which I'm using

Comment: @Nkosi core 2.1

Answer (score 0):

Using [Unity.Microsoft.DependencyInjection](https://github.com/unitycontainer/microsoft-dependency-injection)

> Unity extension to integrate with *Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection* compliant systems

change approach of *Startup*

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

    services.AddMemoryCache(); //<-- Adding memory cache

    services.AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_xxx);

    //...
}

public void ConfigureContainer(IUnityContainer container) {
   // Could be used to register more types
   UnityConfigurationSection section
        = (UnityConfigurationSection) ConfigurationManager.GetSection ("unity");
    section.Configure (container, "primaryUnityContainer");

    var resolver = new UnityDependencyResolver (container);

    container.RegisterInstance<IDependencyResolver> (resolver);

    DependencyContext.Initialize (resolver);
}
```

Note how the DI configuration code has been moved to their respective methods

Everything added to the service collection in `ConfigureServices` will be populated over to the container by the Unity ServiceProviderFactory

Make sure to add container factory when building host to use Unity as default DI

In the `WebHostBuilder` add `UseUnityServiceProvider(...)` method

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
           .UseUnityServiceProvider()   // <---- Add this line
           .UseStartup<Startup>()
           .Build();
```

Comment: I'm havin issues with using Unity.Microsoft.DependencyInjection so as my legacy functionality is from Microsoft.Practices.Unity namespace. Still can't make Unity work as complete DI container

Comment: @mk_yo Update the original question with how this legacy functionality impacts the integration with .net core. Because it appears you are trying to mix version that can cause conflicts.